# Xamarin ios How to add constraints as per superview

Tags: ios, xamarin, constraints

How can we add constraint as per superview :

I have two subviews which should be half of its superview, How can i add constraint according to its superview.

Superview : buttonContainer

Subviews  : phoneButton, greyVerticalLine, directionButton.

buttonContainer's Superview : contentContainer.

contentContainer's Superview : scrollContainer (UIScroll View).

scrollContainer's Superview : UIView (Main View).

Constraints added with following Hierarchy :

```
buttonContainer.SubviewsDoNotTranslateAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints();

 buttonContainer.AddConstraints(

    phoneButton.AtTopOf(buttonContainer),
    phoneButton.AtLeftOf(buttonContainer),
    phoneButton.Width().EqualTo(),
    phoneButton.Height().GreaterThanOrEqualTo(42),

    greyVerticalLine.AtTopOf(buttonContainer),
    greyVerticalLine.ToRightOf(phoneButton),
    greyVerticalLine.Width().EqualTo(1),
    greyVerticalLine.Height().GreaterThanOrEqualTo(43),

    directionButton.AtTopOf(buttonContainer),
    directionButton.AtRightOf(buttonContainer),
    directionButton.Width().EqualTo(),
    directionButton.Height().GreaterThanOrEqualTo(42)

   );
```

Expectation : I want to set phoneButton and directionButton width half of buttonContainer.

How can i access width of buttonContainer ?

Answer (score 0):

In Xamarin one thing you can do similar to constraining your layout in iOS is using Grid with either custom row or column definitions. Consider the following.

```
<Grid>
      <Grid.RowDefinitions>
           <RowDefinition />
           <RowDefinition />
      </Grid.RowDefinitions>
</Grid>
```

When declaring items using Grid.Row="1" and Grid.Row="2" inside the grid you will see that both are taking up exactly 50% of the grid's height. If you want to divide the space differently you can do the following.

```
<Grid>
      <Grid.RowDefinitions>
           <RowDefinition Height="4*"/>
           <RowDefinition Height="6*"/>
      </Grid.RowDefinitions>
</Grid>
```

Which will assign 40% of the grid's height to the first row and 60% to the second row.

You can even use constant numbers for height instead of relative values. And you can do the same with Column Definitions.